# Could not parse the JSON file. .Net Core 5.0 Web API

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, asp.net5

I have .Net core web api application targeted to 5.0 version.

Whenever i publish my api and deploy in IIS of my local machine i.e., on windows 10,
am able to get return data in postman from my api.

But, the same published folder if i copy and host to IIS of windows server machine i get below error.

2021-02-18T07:16:03.5549203-05:00 80000002-0004-fd00-b63f-84710c7967bb [ERR] Could not parse the JSON file. (a9f4b9b9)

My controller method is like below:

```
public ActionResult GetContactDetails(Guid contactId)
     {
           var contactDetails = _contactDetailsRepository.GetContactDetailsById(contactId);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Returned contact Details from database for contact Id: {0}.",                    
        contactId);
              return Ok(contactDetails);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Error in retriving contact details for contact Id: {ex.Message}");
            return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a lot to go on, but I would first ask if the server has .NET 5 installed or is your app published as self-contained runtime?

Comment: .Net 5.0 is installed on server

Comment: I think your contactDetails list is empty. Did you check if it has a value?

Comment: There should be more detail in the exception, check for inner exceptions too.

Comment: Maybe you have some malformed appsettings.Production.json file in published folder?

Comment: Published folder doesn't have 'appsettings.Production.json'. I used Publish - Folder  option to publish to local drive

Comment: ContactDetails has data, even if it empty it wont throw error, an empty data like '[]' will be returned

Comment: My appsettings.json looks like below:                                                                           {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Comment: @Swaroop could you please check the "secrets.json" file? does it contain anything or its empty?  what is the appsettings.json file type "UTF-8" or "UTF-8-BOM"?

Comment: Thanks issue resolved. Issue was with wrong setting in dbsetting json file.